# R: Tabulate each column of a sparse matrix against a vector

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a logical sparse matrix, say `m`, (which can be any of `Matrix`, `slam`, or `SparseM` matrices if that makes things faster) that I want to do the following on:

```
for (col in 1:ncol(m)) {
  print(table(m[ , col], logicalV)
}
```

where `logicalV` is a *fixed* logical vector of the same length as rows in `m`. Think of this as creating a confusion matrix per feature in the sparse `m`.

The dimensions I am dealing with for `m` are: (15 ~ 40K) x (75 ~ 125K). This makes just the step of accessing the columns `m[ , col]` really slow.

What I am looking for is a *fast* solution here. Any ideas?

Edit:

Based on the comments, here is an outline of what I am really trying to achieve. I have a bunch of feature selection metrics like *information gain*, *binormal separation*, etc. which are all functions of the confusion matrix (i.e. `table(m[ , col], logicalV)`) as they are functions of the counts of true positives / negatives and false positives / negatives. So for each column and `logicalV`, I need to know counts of both `TRUE`, both `FALSE`, and either `TRUE`. Does that help?

Comment: Do you really want to print 125k tables, or do you want to do something else with them ?

Comment: Not printing. :D That's just to identify the meat of the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you want to do exactly, if it is possible, because it could change the way we look at your question.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing as @juba.  There might be more efficient ways of accomplishing the task than creating multiple tables.  What's the end goal?